# Getting 401 using themoviedb, and retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, themoviedb-api

so I'd wanted to make API call with a dynamic request, but for first, I'd created the "raw" call, hardcoded. So, this address in a web browser works fine

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=API_KEY&with_genres=27
```

Here's the raw API call (which is working also)

```
 @GET("3/discover/movie?api_key=API_KEY&with_genres=27") Call<itemList_model> getHorror();
```

The problem is when I tried to make the genres to dynamic query. I'm getting error 401 with this, don't know why.

```
 @GET("3/discover/movie") Call<itemList_model> test(@Query("API_KEY") String key, @Query("with_genres") String[] id); (there's no difference, if I use the array or not, still getting 401)
```

Retrofit call

```
   public void getListViewItems() {
     String url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/";
     Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
           .baseUrl(url)
          .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
          .build();
     apiCall api = retrofit.create(apiCall.class);
    Call<itemList_model> call = api.test("999ac32d244814bb3415d26876085144", "27");
      call.enqueue(new Callback<itemList_model>() {
     @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<itemList_model> call, Response<itemList_model> response) {
          if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.code());
          }
          Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.code());
      }
       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<itemList_model> call, Throwable t) {
           Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
      }
  });
 }
```

> *Error 401: Authentication failed: You do not have permissions to access the service.

Comment: check the interceptor logs and see what url is generated.

Comment: URL must be like `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=<<API_KEY>>&with_genres=27` so change `test()` method `Query` String

Answer (score 2):

You need to do change like below

change `API_KEY` to `api_key` because in your url key is `api_key`.

```
@GET("3/discover/movie") Call<itemList_model> test(@Query("api_key") String key, @Query("with_genres") String[] id);
```